# How to validate the nested api objects in Playwright spi testing

Tags: playwright

I want to validate the nested api objects. I want to check if the value of 'id' inside the 'data' object is "1"

```
{
  page: 1,
  per_page: 6,
  total: 12,
  total_pages: 2,
  data: [
    {
      id: 1,
      email: 'george.bluth@reqres.in',
      first_name: 'George',
      last_name: 'Bluth',
      avatar: 'https://reqres.in/img/faces/1-image.jpg'
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert your json to a valid one.
And after in java you can do something like this.

```
public class Validation {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      String jsonAnswer = "{'page': 1,'per_page': 6,'total': 12,'total_pages': 2,'data':" +
              " [{'id': 1,'email': 'george.bluth@reqres.in','first_name': 'George','last_name':" +
              " 'Bluth','avatar': 'https://reqres.in/img/faces/1-image.jpg'}]}";
        JsonObject json = JsonParser.parseString(jsonAnswer).getAsJsonObject();
        int id = json.get("data")
                .getAsJsonArray().get(0)
                .getAsJsonObject().get("id").getAsInt();
        if(1 == id){
            System.out.println("Validation passed!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Validation failed!");
        }
    }
}
```